# Insert rows based on comma-separated list

Tags: excel, vba

Some cells in a column contain more that one item separated by commas.

I want a row for all the items.

Here is an example:

**ORIGINAL:**
[image: Pic1]

**SHOULD BE:**
[image: Pic2]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231368/split-strings-in-excel-vba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As jswolf19 mentions, you can use the `SPLIT` function to turn a delimited string in to an array. Then, simply iterate over the items in the array and insert new rows as necessary.

The procedure below should get you started.

I assume your data is in columns A:E, and set this using the `rng` variable. Modify that as needed.

**Code revised per OP Comments**

```
Sub SplitPartsRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim arrParts() As String
Dim partNum As Long
'## In my example i use columns A:E, and column D contains the Corresponding Parts ##

Set rng = Range("A1:BI13876") '## Modify as needed ##'

r = 2
Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
    '## Split the value in column BB (54) by commas, store in array ##
    arrParts = Split(rng(r, 54).Value, ",")
    '## If there's more than one item in the array, add new lines ##
    If UBound(arrParts) >= 1 Then '## corrected this logic for base 0 array
        rng(r, 54).Value = arrParts(0)

        '## Iterate over the items in the array ##
        For partNum = 1 To UBound(arrParts)
            '## Insert a new row ##'
            '## increment the row counter variable ##
            r = r + 1
            rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            '## Copy the row above ##'
            rng.Rows(r).Value = rng.Rows(r - 1).Value

            '## update the part number in the new row ##'
            rng(r, 54).Value = Trim(arrParts(partNum))

            '## resize our range variable as needed ##
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count)

        Next

    End If
'## increment the row counter variable ##
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: This is great, thanks! However, what is the significance of E3 in "Set rng = Range("A1:E3") "

Comment: In my example data, column E is the last column in my table, and row 3 is the last row in my table, ergo, `E3` is the last cell in the table.  So, we are setting the `rng` variable to represent the table beginning in cell `A1` and ending in cell `E3`.

Comment: isnt E4 the last cell though?

Comment: Yes. When I first wrote the code it was only A1:E3, though. So, you can modify that as needed so that it represents the table correctly. I'll revise my code above.

Comment: So I am implementing the code to my current set of data.. the info I need to split is in column "BB".. which would mean replace all the 4s in the code with 54 right? I did that and nothing has happened... i also changed my range to "A1: BI13876".. however it isnt working :(

Comment: @Shivster, I can see you're a relatively new member to StackOverflow. This is just a friendly reminder to mark as accepted the answer that you found best answered your question, in this case, the one provided by David Zemens.

Comment: @DavidZemens also, the code stops after it fixes the first cell it encounters with teh commas. How would I stop that? So sorry for all tehse questions, this is the first time im working with excel vba

Comment: @Shivster correct, this code is splitting the value in column 4, by `arrParts = Split(rng(r, 4).Value, ",")`. Change the `4` to the numeric column # for column `BB`.  Also change `rng(r, 4).Value = arrParts(0)` and `rng(r + 1, 4).Value = Trim(arrParts(partNum))` which are likewise currently referring to column 4.  If you can upload your file to Dropbox or GoogleDocs, I can take a look at it.

Comment: @DavidZemens Hi David, unfortunately I cannot send you the file as it is considered "confidential" :$ Please do let me know what part of this code initates the creation of the new row with the necessary info or how to make the code terminating at the last possible cell in my BB column

Comment: You may consider scrubbing/anonymizing the data, or sending only 3 or 4 rows of "dummy" data (which would be fake/non-confidential data). The `For ... Next` loop already will terminate at the last row you define in the `rng` variable. This line `rng.Rows(r + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown` inserts rows.

Comment: you can email to me dzemens at gmail

Comment: @DavidZemens sent you an email, may have fallen into your spam folder

Answer (score 1):

Try this as macro:

```
Sub mcrSplit_and_Insert()
    Dim i As Long, r As Long, rws As Long, c As Range, vC As Variant
    On Error GoTo FallThrough
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    For r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If InStr(1, Cells(r, 4).Value, ",") > 0 Then
            rws = Len(Cells(r, 4).Value) - Len(Replace(Cells(r, 4).Value, ",", vbNullString))
            Cells(r + 1, 4).Resize(rws, 1).EntireRow.Insert
            Cells(r, 1).Resize(rws + 1, 9).FillDown
            For i = 0 To rws
                For Each c In Cells(r + i, 1).Resize(1, 9)
                    If InStr(1, c.Value, ",") > 0 Then
                        vC = Split(c.Value, ",")
                        c = vC(i)
                    End If
                    If IsNumeric(c) Then c = c.Value
                Next c
            Next i
        End If
    Next r
    Columns(2).NumberFormat = "m/d/yy"
FallThrough:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also can be done via:

1. Data - Import from;
2. After the source is imported in the Query Mode right click on the required column and choose "Split Columns".
3. In the dialogue click 'advanced' and change splitting mode from columns to rows.