# Splitting text with semi colons in two columns and one to one mapping with corresponding data duplicated

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I need help on tweaking the code below. The screenshot is listed below the code labeled 'Screenshot'. It is a sample format of a similar data I am trying to separate. I have 3000+ rows of data in this format. The code below is able to split one column and duplicate the data but now I have to do a one to one mapping with the location and dates as well as duplicate all the corresponding data. Any input would be really appreciated.

I want the data to not only split at the semi colons into separate rows but to also map the dates with each corresponding location and to duplicate the data next to them.

This is the code that I had been using on one particular column. Thanks in advance! Source of the code is from a post on stack overflow: A very useful code. [Scripting in Excel - Insert new row based on comma-separated list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16546311/scripting-in-excel-insert-new-row-based-on-comma-separated-list/16546973#16546973)

```
Sub SplitPartsRows()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As Long
Dim arrParts() As String
Dim partNum As Long
Dim Trail As String
'## In my example i use columns A:E, and column D contains the Corresponding Parts ##

Set rng = Range("A1:BI13876") '## Modify as needed ##'

r = 2

Do While r <= rng.Rows.Count
    '## Split the value in column BB (54) by commas, store in array ##
    arrParts = Split(rng(r, 17).Value, ";")
    '## If there's more than one item in the array, add new lines ##
    If UBound(arrParts) >= 1 Then '## corrected this logic for base 0 array
        rng(r, 17).Value = arrParts(0)

        '## Iterate over the items in the array ##
        For partNum = 1 To UBound(arrParts)
            '## Insert a new row ##'
            '## increment the row counter variable ##
            r = r + 1
            rng.Rows(r).Insert Shift:=xlDown

            '## Copy the row above ##'
            rng.Rows(r).Value = rng.Rows(r - 1).Value

            '## update the part number in the new row ##'
            rng(r, 17).Value = Trim(arrParts(partNum))

            '## resize our range variable as needed ##
            Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count + 1, rng.Columns.Count)

        Next

    End If
'## increment the row counter variable ##
r = r + 1
Loop

End Sub
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EHar6.jpg)

Comment: Screenshots of your input and expected output would help here.

Comment: I added the screenshot to the post. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Acknowledged. First time using stack overflow to post the question. Wasn't aware of that. It is now acknowledged!

Comment: Two points: 1) posting sample data as a screen shot alone is not useful - do you expect people to type it out? 2) what have _you_ done to solve this?  Simply dumping your requirements on SO and asking people to do your work is not what SO is for

Comment: I said: Any input as in any guidance would be appreciated I don't expect the whole code to be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub Reformat()
    Dim rwIn As Range, rwOut As Range
    Dim arrLoc, arrDt, locs, dts, i

    Set rwIn = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:E2")
    Set rwOut = ActiveSheet.Range("G2:K2")

    Do While Application.CountA(rwIn) > 0
        locs = rwIn.Cells(2).Value
        dts = rwIn.Cells(4).Value

        If Len(locs) > 0 And Len(dts) > 0 Then
            arrLoc = Split(locs, ";")
            arrDt = Split(dts, ";")
            For i = LBound(arrLoc) To UBound(arrLoc)
                With rwOut
                    .Cells(1) = rwIn.Cells(1)
                    .Cells(2) = arrLoc(i)
                    .Cells(3) = rwIn.Cells(3)
                    If i <= UBound(arrDt) Then
                        .Cells(4) = arrDt(i)
                    End If
                    .Cells(5) = rwIn.Cells(5)
                End With
                Set rwOut = rwOut.Offset(1, 0)
            Next i
        End If
        Set rwIn = rwIn.Offset(1, 0)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much Tim! It worked like a charm. I really needed to understand the logic. I have never written a macro nor have I ever coded and this project fell into my lap. And thank you for writing it in a way that I could really understand what is going on in the code! I really appreciate it! Thank you!!!!