# Is there away to call Multiple Items from single cell

Tags: excel, vba

I was wondering if it would be possible to call out several items from a single cell? I am very limited in space so having one cell with all the information would be a great benefit. for example if i had a single cell that had "Dog,2,5,8" the program could run the program could tell what it meant and run my calculation? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You can use `Split()` in VBA to separate the content on the comma.

Answer (score 0):

As @Tim Williams said, Split() will do what you want.

```
Sub splitcell()
  Dim TestString As String
  TestString = CStr(Range("A3").Value)

  Dim TestArray() As String
  TestArray() = Split(TestString, ", ")

  MsgBox (TestArray(0) & vbNewLine & TestArray(1) & vbNewLine & TestArray(2) & vbNewLine & TestArray(3))
End Sub
```

[image]

Macro will give you this message box:

[image]

Now you can just iterate through the TestArray() with a For loop and do your logic.

See MSDN documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f(v=vs.90).aspx)

And here is another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8231368/split-strings-in-excel-vba)